# android:installLocation "preferExternal" on KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-external-storage

I'm trying to install an app directly on the SD on a 4.4.2. kitkat Android tablet.
The problem is that , although I have specified

```
    android:installLocation "preferExternal"
```

the app always is installed on the internal memory.
If I do the same process on a 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich android device, it works!
How can I fix this on the tablet?
Thanks!

Comment: i suggest you to use android:installLocation="auto" .

Comment: Thanks, but the app is installed on the internal storage with 'auto', too. Even if the SD is almost empty and the internal is almost full...

Comment: On 4.0.4 is installed on SD directly...